# Number of seconds in 6 weeks

Tags: mathematics

Using only 3 characters (any single digit or one of the following operators: $ +,\, -,\, \times,\, \div,\, ! $), construct an expression that evaluates to the number of seconds in 6 weeks.

Comment: Usual..+,-,/,!,x

Comment: ^I added this information in to the original post. In the future, if you post questions like these, please make sure that all possible specifications are included. Thanks! :)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the question..I am a novice to the site and hopefully improve as I go along.

Comment: is × multiplication?

Comment: Has a correct answer been given? If so, please don't forget to $\color{green}{\checkmark \small\text{Accept}}$ it.  (That indicates what the correct answer is, so there's no doubt; it also awards the successful answerer for their effort, and as an added bonus, gives you +2 rep for doing it! It's also just good etiquette for this site. You have several questions right now that seem to have good answers, and none have been accepted; please consider doing so. Thanks!)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One answer is:

> '$10!$' = 3628800 = (60*60*24*7*6)

And for fun, the original question accidentally asked to solve for **3** weeks.  An argument could be made that the following works:

> '$9!5$' evaluates to (9! * 5) = 1814400 = (60*60*24*7*3)

Comment: I'm not entirely sure about your solution for 3 weeks, since it implicitly assumes that two numbers next to each other is multiplication, which is not always the case (concatenation is another possibility). But kudos for trying to find a way to do it!

Comment: @PiIsNot3 When an operator is involved, concatenation is hardly an option. The *real* problem with this solution is that it could be $9$ times the **subfactorial** of $5$...